# Database design for an online evaluation system

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm working on an online employee evaluation system and I found myself in trouble while trying to find the best table design for this project. Until now I have the following tables: users, campaigns, forms, chapters, questions. Each evaluation campaign must have one or more forms, each form must have one or more chapters and each chapter must have one or more questions. My current table layout is here: http://cl.ly/image/3z441W2J3t1r

There are two types of users: employees and managers. When it comes to evaluation, employees have to fill in a single form (an autoevaluation), while the managers must complete their autoevaluation and the evaluation of each employee.

With this in mind, how should I design the tables for the allocation of the forms for each user?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse Managers and Employees.  All Managers are Employees when it comes to completing an auto-evaluation, but only Managers write an evaluation of other Employees.

So for auto-evaluations you just need a foreign key between FORMS and USERS on USER_ID.  For managerial evaluations you need  a foreign key between FORMS and USERS on (MANAGER_GUID, USER_ID).

Incidentally why have you got two different datatypes for MANAGER_GUID and USER_ID?  A Manager is just a USER who manages other users, so MANAGER_ID ought to be a foreign key on USER_ID.